# Batch File - Renaming a copied file with User input for the file name

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch files and I'm trying to edit a code I made recently for simple folder and subfolder creation.

Here is my current code

```
@echo -
@echo PLEASE READ NOTES CAREFULLY
@echo -
@echo PLease Enter Project number and name inside quotation marks
@echo Example: "100 test folder"
@echo -
@echo -
@echo off
set /p dname= Name:
xcopy /e/i "C:\<Parent folder>\TEMPLATE" %dname%
ren %dname%\infotemp.xlsx "INFO %dname%.xlsx"
```

The xcopy command is working perfectly and copies all folder\subfolders and 2 excel files.  My issue is with the renaming the excel files.
The %dname% ultimately will look like

```
456 Project Name
```

The file name should end up looking like

```
INFO 456 Project Name.xlsx
```

If the dname is set without spaces I can rename the file using the above code.

```
dname="456ProjectName"
```

When the user enters a space on the prompt

```
dname="456(SPACE)Project(SPACE)Name"
```

it errors and does not rename the file

I've been researching and trying to figure this out with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you use the correct/recommended syntax?

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo -
Echo PLEASE READ NOTES CAREFULLY
Echo -
Echo Please enter project number and name
Echo Example: 100 test folder
Echo -
Echo -
Set /P "dname= Name: "
XCopy "C:\<Parent folder>\TEMPLATE" "%dname%" /E /I
Ren "%dname%\infotemp.xlsx" "INFO %dname%.xlsx"
```

Comment: That fixed it!  I still have a lot to learn.  I seemed to be on the right track but in the wrong order.  Thank you for the advice!